# Show to be deleted items in popup window

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-view

I am using Odoo 10e. I want a simple functionality that whenever i wanted to delete one or more then one item from a list view or from a specific list view only. I want to show all of the items which are selected for deleted to show their name in popup window so that user can have a quick review what's he is going to delete. I know user can see details in list view but i want to give a glimpse to user in shape of model window that this is going to be deleted. Are you sure to delete ?

If user click Confirm then normal delete case should work.

As far i research and worked on it, i have idea that it should be something regarding overriding the `do_delete` method in the `list_view.js` in the web module. But i didn't know much about javascript overriding for Odoo.

Comment: Do you need it for all method delete of your Odoo?

Comment: I am trying to create an example . So it would be good if you let me know for all/ and for a specific view

Comment: It's for V10 community?

Comment: V10 Enterprise. I mentioned this in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example how I do it.

I called the name_get for your model and records ids, this names list, I change the text of confirming message with the information of ids selected.

```
do_delete: function (ids) {

    new Model(this.model)
    .call('name_get', [ids, this.dataset.get_context()]).done(function (names) {


        var text = _t("Do you really want to remove these records?") + ' '+ names.join(' \n')
        if (!(ids.length && confirm(text))) {
            return;
        }
        var self = this;

        return $.when(this.dataset.unlink(ids)).done(function () {
            _(ids).each(function (id) {
                self.records.remove(self.records.get(id));
            });
            // Hide the table if there is no more record in the dataset
            if (self.display_nocontent_helper()) {
                self.no_result();
            } else {
                if (self.records.length && self.current_min === 1) {
                    // Reload the list view if we delete all the records of the first page
                    self.reload();
                } else if (self.records.length && self.dataset.size() > 0) {
                    // Load previous page if the current one is empty
                    self.pager.previous();
                }
                // Reload the list view if we are not on the last page
                if (self.current_min + self._limit - 1 < self.dataset.size()) {
                    self.reload();
                }
            }
            self.update_pager(self.dataset);
            self.compute_aggregates();
        });
    });;
},
```

Comment: I am getting this error `ReferenceError: Model is not defined`. Also can you let me know if i want to get any field other then `Name` from model

Comment: You need import `var Model = require('web.DataModel');`and you can replace `.call('name_get', ... ` by  `.call('read', [ids, ['name', 'display_name'], this.dataset.get_context()])`

Comment: Thanks Sir, You're Awesome !

Comment: Slowly and safely compliments, I'll end up loving it! :D

Comment: I am having an issue that it only works when in enable `debug mode`. Is there any way around for this ?